# Redirects or Routing for Landing Page URL's?

Tags: redirect, routing

I am trying to set up a channel that uses different content for a series of Google Adwords landing pages.

I set up the channel template as /landing-pages/_entry

I'd like to remove the /landing-pages/ piece of the title

Ideally, I'd like short simple url, which is effectively the slug title, which would be something like /chef-jobs for this client.

What is the best way to achieve this with Craft? Redirects or Routing.

The routing method doesn't call the entry and just shows a blank template, how can I feed the route address across if I use this method?

Any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either set the URL Format of the landing pages channel to `{slug}` (the same as your normal pages)

Or you could try putting the landing pages in the normal pages structure, but give them a new entry type so you can use different fields.

Comment: Many thanks, both answers are similar, but both helped. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

No redirects or custom routes needed, just set the URI to `{slug}` in your channel settings. The path to your template setting `landing-pages/_entry` is only necessary for Craft internally, it does not affect the URL.

Comment: Many thanks Carlcs :) Answer much appreciated.